# JS Regexp for letter that appears at least twice anywhere in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

**`/([a-zA-Z]).*?\1/`**

This regular expression currently returns true on .test() if it finds 1 matching repeating letter. I want it to match atleast 3 or 2 for that matter and return true.

For example, currently it returns true on `.test()` for strings like;

```
Trickster, Been, Dekko
```

But I want it to return true **only if** there are more than 2 matches so that the following would return true on `.test()`

```
CordCord, XoXo, XolXol, PiunPiun
```

And **NOT** return true on the strings I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Please check my answer. And no, the question is not bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{2,}` after `[a-zA-Z]` to match 2 or more occurrences of the pattern:

```
([a-zA-Z]{2,}).*?\1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gCAQah/1)

**Details**

- `([a-zA-Z]{2,})` - Capturing group 1 matching 2 or more ASCII letters
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line breaks, as few as possible (lazy)
- `\1` - backreference matching the same text as captured in Group 1.

Note that the 2 or more ASCII letters should be captured into 1 group (hence the limiting quantifier is inside the capturing parentheses).

```js
var ss = ['Trickster, Been, Dekko', 'CordCord, XoXo, XolXol, PiunPiun'];
var re = /([a-zA-Z]{2,}).*?\1/;
for (var s of ss) {
  console.log(s,"=>",re.test(s));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! +1

Answer (score 1):

You could specify at least three like this: `/([a-zA-Z]){3,}.*?\1/`

```
> /([a-zA-Z]){3,}.*?\1/.test('Been')
<- false
> /([a-zA-Z]){3,}.*?\1/.test('CordCord')
<- true
```

Comment: Check out "Limiting Repetition" under http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html